# Do different hunters have different projectile speeds?

Tags: smite

This question is more of a confirmation of my "feelings".

Do Hunter's projectiles travel at different speeds? For example, Anhur's thrown javelin looks and 'feels' slower than Ah Muzen Cab's ... whatever he shoots. Is it simply a trick of the eye because Ah Muzen Cab's projectile is much smaller?

I've had considerably more trouble landing hits with other hunters (Anhur being my main) which doesn't really make sense if they all have the same projectile speed.

Comment: You are correct, I'll post my answer to this question when I get back to work from lunch :)

Comment: K, I can't find it. But I DO remember reading that they nerf some gods because their projectile speed is too fast. I just doesn't affect hunters, but all god classes. I thought I remember reading it in patch notes all the time, but I can't find a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

From [a reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/1w8n4b/nu_was_inhand_attacks_arrive_to_their_target/):

**Nu Wa's Inhand attacks arrive to their target slower than other Gods**

Apollo used as reference. Both shot from same distance to max range, attack animation started at same time.

Nu Wa Delay: .25 Sec. Apollo Delay: .21 Sec. (Edit: Those are frames, not MS, with a 30 Frames per second recording, it's actually closer to .14 sec if I'm not mistaken)

Video for reference:

Edit #2: Updated with new Nu Wa vs Chronos speed:

Could quite possibly be intentional, but having a God with Inhands being their main form of damage having slower travel time than others is discouraging, causing the others to be better in a large amount of circumstances.

---

Chances are that yes, different hunters do have different projectile speeds. Possibly to give the hunters more variety.

Comment: Is there one between Hunter vs Hunter? it does confirm there are different speeds, but that's between a Mage(nuwa) and a Hunter(apollo). That's a little expected (assassins attack much faster than guardians and warriors).

Comment: @Rapitor I could not find one. I guess that there is a possibility that it could be a trick of the eye (I have not played Smite, but I assume that two Hunters should have the same firing speeds. If an assassin has a faster firing speed than there is a chance that all assassins have the same firing difference from Hunters and therefore all Hunters have the same firing speed. Maybe its class related) but the length of the projectile would contribute to when it hits. So the speed is the same, but the time until it hits is differed. Of course, this is completely abstract theory. But its my take.